# Why does my DatePicker not hide?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

Whenever I click the row above my date picker, my date picker does not hide like it should. Rather when I click the row, it just permanently highlights to dark grey, typical to when you click something initially. Why is this happening? Why doesn't my datePicker hide?

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
private var datePickerHidden = false



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    datePickerChanged()
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

}

@IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    detailLabel.text = formatter.string(from:sender.date)
}

func datePickerChanged () {
    detailLabel.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: datePicker.date, dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.short, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style.short)
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        toggleDatepicker()
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
}

private func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if !datePickerHidden && indexPath.row == 1 {
        return 0
    }
    else {
        return 100
    }
}

private func toggleDatepicker() {

    datePickerHidden = !datePickerHidden

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Move `datePickerHidden = !datePickerHidden` after `tableView.beginUpdates()`. Check if it works if `datePickerHidden` initialized with `true`

Comment: I tried this and had no luck

Comment: how you are showing the picker ?. Are clicking in first row of tableview then only `toggleDatepicker` will be called . Your code was written like this. are you hiding the picker in storyboard or XIB

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this:

```
datePickerHidden = !datePickerHidden 
datePicker.hidden = datePickerHidden
```